# Using class library with WCF service in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core

In my project I have a class library that contains connections for WCF services.

In old ASP.NET MVC in order to use service methods I only needed to add bindings in my web.config and it would work properly.

The issue that I am having now is that when I call web service in ASP.NET5 I get this exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'xxx' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. 
This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
```

Is there a way that I can add my binding in a similar way as I would do in old MVC apps?

Comment: You don't really have to add bindings to a config file. Instead, create them programatically.

Comment: I am using this library in several MVC projects in the solution and would like to use the same approach. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the configuration below from an MVC app. When you add a reference to your WCF service using the add service ref dialog. A client section will get added to your System.ServiceModel section in your web.config. It should specify the endpoint which what seems to be missing based on the error you're getting.

Hope this helps

```
    <client>

  <endpoint address="http://address.to.your.service.com:8080/V3/ConfigService.svc" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="ConfigService.V3.ConfigHttpServiceBinding" 
            contract="ConfigService.IConfigService" 
            name="ConfigService.V3.ConfigHttpService"/>
    </client
```

Comment: I have that configuration for MVC5 apps in solution, but for MVC6 I do not have web.config and I would like to use the same service while debugging and running on IIS Express

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run by programattically config bindings. thanks to @wiktor-zychla comment.

```
var documentService = new DocumentServiceClient(
                                  new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None),
                                  new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:60205/DocumentService.svc"));
```